# App crashs on opening the PDF for second time

Tags: pdf, rhomobile, rhodes

I have method which generates a pdf and opens it when the method is called.

```
generate_pdf()
file_location = File.join(Rho::RhoApplication.get_app_path('public'),'pdfs/File110.pdf')
System.open_url(file_location)
```

Now on the `generate_pdf()` i have,

```
pdf = PDF::Writer.new
x = pdf.absolute_left_margin - 10
y = pdf.absolute_top_margin - 10
pdf.add_text(x,y,"Hello World",20)
file_location = File.join(Rho::RhoApplication.get_app_path('public'),'pdfs/File110.pdf')
pdf.save_as(file_location)
```

So the above code runs only for the first time. On second click the app crashes. 
What's wrong with the code ?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is really interesting. This happened to me in one of my project.

`You are not closing the pdf after that is being opened by the application.`

You need to close the pdf opened in your default viewer.

When on second click, the application tries to create and stored at the same place as before but as the file is opened in some default reader, application don't get permission to store it and crashes.

So the point you can raise is that, if this is the case then what would happen if the user opens the pdf and just minimize it. So at that time, the app will crash.

But the answer is `NO`. The crashing only happens in RhoSimulator, not on the Simulator or real device. On device, there would be no issue regarding permissions.

So you can proceed with releasing the app without any tension.